# should i have to pay Haq mehr after divorce rukhsati didnt happen (Sunni Barelvi only)

Tags: talaq

i married a girl who was in love with someone else.

we delayed rukhsati for some financial problems at my end.
we never had sex she stayed at her fathers house.

i've given her divorce now she asked for it .
now his dad is asking me to pay haq mehr do i have to pay it?

Need answer according to **Sunni Barelvi maslik**

Comment: What is meant by "haq" and "rukhsati"?

Comment: In Islam, Haq-Mehr is a mandatory payment, in the form of money or possessions paid by the groom, to the bride at the time of marriage, that legally becomes her property. Rukhsati is Urdu language term. rukhsati literal meaning is Departure. the term is used that after nikah sometimes the girl stays at her fathers home and when they send the girl to her husband the ceremony is called Barat/rukhstai in pakistan and india.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already determined mehr and then Nikah ended with divorce without dakhul, you need to pay half mehr.

> And if you divorce them before you have touched them and you have
>   already specified for them an obligation, then [give] half of what you
>   specified - unless they forego the right or the one in whose hand is
>   the marriage contract foregoes it. And to forego it is nearer to
>   righteousness. And do not forget graciousness between you. Indeed
>   Allah, of whatever you do, is Seeing.
>
> Surah Al-Baqarah 237